# How to find xpath of a text element without node

Tags: xpath, nodes, parent

```
 <h1>
<span class="visually-hidden">BBC Radio</span>
   Search results for 'archers'  
</h1>
```

I want to locate the text element "Search results for 'archers'" . What will be the xpath that will locate to it and not to the element in span node ??

Answer (score 1):

For your input sample

```
/h1/text()
```

Tested on  http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

returns Search results for 'archers'